# Underscore bindAll: preserving the 'this' context

Tags: javascript, this, underscore.js

I am having issues attempting to preserve `uploader` as the `this` context when `onSubmit` is called. Can any JS gurus help out?

```
uploader: {

        init: function(){
            var that = this;

            var fileUploader = new Uploader.FileUploaderBasic({
                    button      : $("#upload-btn")[0],
                    action      : "/filesCollection",
                    onSubmit    : that.onSubmit
                });

            _.bindAll(this, this.onSubmit); // attempting to bind 'this'
        },


        onSubmit: function(id, fileName){
            console.log(this); // still refers to 'fileUploader' object :(
        }

}
```

**Results in the following error:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/WilsonPage/BE3Lp/5/

Comment: Came across this really great explanation of `_.bind` and `_.bindAll`: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2011/08/18/understanding-bind-and-bindall-in-backbone.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem Solved: http://jsfiddle.net/WilsonPage/BE3Lp/41/

**Several Important Things I Discovered:**

1. The `_.bindAll()` must be called before the function is assigned.
2. The first argument must be the object or `this` you wish to bind.
3. The arguments that follow must be the names of the functions present within the object (`this`) and they must be in **string form!**
4. If you want to bind all functions in the object (`this`) then omit any function names and have the object (`this`) as the only argument eg. `_.bindAll(this)`

*Hope this helps some confused peeps like me!*

Comment: `_.bindAll(this)` no longer works as of underscore 1.4.4. Using `_.bindAll.apply(_, [this].concat(_.functions(this)));` seems to work well ([src](https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder/issues/142#issuecomment-23748452))

Answer (score 1):

By using `call` or `apply` you can specify the context for `this` for any function. This should do the trick (in the fileUploader declaration):

```
onSubmit: function() {
    that.onSubmit.apply(that, arguments);
}
```

**Edit:** Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WDTBV/1/

Comment: Could you demonstrate in the JSFiddle?

Comment: Isn't that just the same as doing this: http://jsfiddle.net/WilsonPage/WDTBV/4/. I don't see how apply() is neccessary.

Comment: No, it is not quite the same. `apply` takes an argument list as an array, and sends the arguments to the function normally. There are many ways to solve this however, not all of which require `apply`.

Comment: I would really like to understand why the _.bindAll() method is not working in this example.